# Files Installation for a NsDialog NSIS page

Tags: windows, nsis, nsdialogs

I have written my installer pages with the custom UI needed. I dont understand where to put the actual installation part code. 
For eg: I want to extract some files and stamp them.

I have a installation progress bar status page. I am trying to perform all these operations while user is on this page.

Wrote a function as follows

```
Function MyInstallFun

;Extract something
;Execute msi file
;Execute bat file

FunctionEnd
```

I tried following approach

```
Page custom ProgressPage MyInstallFun
```

But this way the part is executed on after user clicks Next

Also, Tried `Call MyInstallFun` from inside of `Function ProgressPage` but the UI looks blank for a while until operations take place and then progress Page is displayed which is wrong.

Can someone please suggest how to install some heavy files using NSDialog custom page?

Comment: In short I want to implement something like this but on my custom page. How to make my progress page make implement actions under default section?
Page instfiles

Section

 DetailPrint "hello world"

SectionEnd

Comment: I want to mimic the Page instfiles on my custom Page for progress bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really supposed to perform long operations on other pages. You could try running the operation in a [background thread](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/BgWorker_plug-in)...

Comment: The operations are actual installation files I would have to perform those to install the software on client machine. The thing I am not able to do is how to do it on my custom page.

Comment: Installing something after the user clicked "Next" and not "Install" is not really OK IMHO. Why is using the instfiles page problem?

Comment: The instfiles page does not show the custom UI that I want.